# Parsing "number @ number" and similar sequences

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I'm working on a parser function, which will eventually be used to for steel component weight calculations. The function takes a simple input string and returns individual values (amount, caliber, separation) as variables in a list.

For example, it should take "5#5" (5 number 5 bars) and return [5,5,0]. Or "#5@250" (number 5 bars spaced 250 mm) and return [0,5,250]. Easy enough.

My approach is to use a regex for it, and then re.search or split to get the individual components. First case regex would be "\d+#\d+", second one "#\d+@\d+".

The problem is when my input has decimals. There's cases in which someone might specify "#5@122.5". In that case my regex messes up and I get "122" instead of "122.5". I've been looking at regex for floating point numbers, but from what I've seen, the expression gets huge, real fast.

And in the future, I want to add support for expressions like "#5@250l500t" (#5 at 250mm lenghtwise and 500mm crosswise) which makes the regex even larger and more complicated.

Which makes me wonder: is regex the best way to go about this? Or is there something else I could use that would work better to detect the expression format, and separate accordingly?

Comment: You could just use a simple regexp like `[\d.]+` if you don't need to reject invalid numbers like `1.2.3`

Comment: It might be easier to do the regex in two stages - one to extract individual fields between their respective separators, and then another to parse each individual field as desired

Comment: Is there a separator between each set of values? Could we have two sets represented by `5#55#5@250`? This could be either `[5, 5, 0], [5, 5, 250]` or `[5, 55, 0], [0, 5, 250]`. You can generally capture float values with `(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)`

Comment: Not really, since this is only a basic parse function. Something like 5#55#5@250 would be an error case. In the final product, two sets would be separated (5#55 #5@250), and they'd go through a split and then be parsed individually.

Comment: @Barmar [\d.]+ got me out of the rut for the time being. It's looking like this:  
`caliber = re.search("#[\d.]+",rebarspec).group()` and then `caliber = int(separation.replace("#",""))` to convert the string to a float/int as needed

Comment: The pattern can be a bit long, but it is a repetition of pieces `(?<!\S)(?:\d*\.?\d+#\d*\.?\d+|#\d*\.?\d+@\d*\.?\d+(?:l\d*\.?\d+t)?)(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/h9VELg/1 If you want to know which part matched, you could also use a capture group https://regex101.com/r/ipDLw2/1

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion you should avoid using the regex in this case and try something like this (which is primitive, but could be easily extended for more elaborate needs):

```
def bar_split(text):
    if "@" not in text:
        print(text.split("#") + ["0"])
    else:
        print(["0"] + text[1:].split("@"))


bar_split("5#5")    # ['5', '5', '0']
bar_split("#5@250") # ['0', '5', '250']
```